# Angular show snackbar after navigation

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have two components. In the first one on successful server response I want to do the following:

```
this.router.navigate(['']);
this.snackBarMessage = 'Successfully submitted';
```

Then the page is being redirected to another component and I would like to show the snackBarMessage message just there e.g (ngOnInit())

Something like that:

```
this.snackBarService.openSnackBar(snackBarMessage, 'Close', 9999999);
```

My snackBarService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SnackBarService {

  constructor(private matSnackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  openSnackBar(message: string, action: string, duration?: number) {
    this.matSnackBar.open(message, action, { duration });
  }
}
```

How can I achieve that? How can I pass `snackBarMessage` to another component after navigation?

Comment: On the final component, will this message change or always display a success ?

Comment: The message should be adjustable. The final component should receive what receives as param. Additionally, this page not always displays snackBar - it is landing page actually.

Comment: You can either use [a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) or [a resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data), or even both together.

Comment: How do you want the message to be displayed? I would place a _span_ or whatever you want the message to look like, in the template of the _app-root_ and bind that span for example like `<span *ngIf="globals.message">{{globals.message}}</span>`. _message_ then sould be a global viariable, that you access in your component via dependency injection.

Comment: @schlonzo this is a snacker from Angular Material : https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview

Comment: @MaryannahOh I see. Didn't know that. Then I would go your way.

Comment: you can check  @Input() and @Output() to transfer the data from one component to another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

``` this.router.navigate([``]) ``` returns a promise to which you can subscribe to. This promise will be executed after the navigation was successful. Please see this [Documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) for further information.

```js
this.router.navigate(['']).then((navigated: boolean) => {
    if(navigated) {
      this.snackBarService.openSnackBar(snackBarMessage, 'Close', 9999999);
    }
});
```

Comment: But it's in the origin component, not in the destination component.

Comment: @Maryannah It will be displayed when the destination component is loaded, which is what the OP wants: "and I would like to show the snackBarMessage message just there e.g (ngOnInit())"

Comment: And what happens if the destination component is the same, but not the origin component ? If the destination component can be accessed from 450 components, will you write your function 450 times ?

Comment: This was not a question about 450 components but 2.

Comment: @Maryannah considering a scenario with 450 components, in which the message of the snackbar depends on the source component and not the destination, it would still be necessary to do "something" for every single component in order to set that message. Having to call 1 function does not seem like a bad "something" to start with.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo that implies having to change 450 methods if, for instance, the duration change, writing 450xN more lines of code (since the service would only take one), and not abstract a function that is re-used 450 times. Frankly, I don't mind, that's not my project. If people want to use bad design, that's on them. I'm just pointing it out, and you or the author trying to justify it doesn't change that fact.

Comment: Again, you are discussing about a solution to a problem that ATM does not exist...

Comment: @Jota.Toledo and again, a problem doesn't need to exist to learn coding with best practices in mind. And I'm not the one discussing it in the first place, I simply explained the reason of my downvote, and the author tried to justify it, then you did the same. Seeing it bothers all of us, we'll stay there, see you around !

Answer (score 0):

You may show the message and then navigate:

Using the afterDismissed() method:

```
this.snackBar.open('msg', 'close', {
                  duration: 2000
                }).afterDismissed().subscribe(()=>{
                  this.router.navigate(['']);
                });
```